# Any way to make the JPA persist objects faster?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

using JPA,Hibernate/ MVC / Servlets, I am trying to upload a .csv file inside my database. The file is 90k+ rows long. What i managed to get working is upload the .csv with Servlet, read every row and split the rows to insert as columns. In my while loop I create the EntityManager, insert the data in a new object, persist and commit. I works but it took about 5hrs to pass through all the data. Is there anything I can change? I am relatively new to programming. Here is my code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(myCSVasInputStream).useDelimiter("\\n");
while(s.hasNext()) {
try{
EntityManager em = JPAUtils.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
String row = s.next();
String[] column = row.split(;);
myEntity m = new myEntity();
m.setValue(column[0]);
em.persist(m);
em.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (Excepltion e) {
system.out.print("I think i need to catch exception for duplicate rows");
}
}
```

Comment: Yours is about the slowest way possible. You can search for "batch insert" to find different ways (without JPA too, since it's completely unnecessary).

Comment: do you need to create entitymanager at every row?

Answer (score 0):

Even old 2010 computers with HDD would insert 1000 rows/sec easily.
But you have to avoid bad software/algos.

checklist:

a) double check your DB tuning. A dev mode mysql for instance is a crappy reference to a real server. It has minuscule buffers, pools, etc... A linux VM would import a mysqldump 10x faster than a windows one... just as an example... Make the server ready for hard work.

b) if you were to put @Transactional on everything, it's possible you would be going through a lot of java stack frames for each row. Check if you are cpu bounded. You should be io bounded normally for such insert. Here you do TXN on every row...

c) don't try to make a single transaction of 90000 rows either, that's just silly. I know you are not, keep it that way. Maybe simply avoid TXN entirely since I can't see the benefit for your case.

If you can avoid hibernate, then you have a few options:

d) clearly a server-side prepared statement is preferable.

e) on top of prepared statement, use batchstatement (could do 20-100 at a time for a start, find sweet spot).

f) if you are really not faint of heart, and have nobody in your way to complain about thing they don't understand and block your pull request in a damn code review (!), you can actually have mysql read the CSV directly, with load-ready files (LOAD DATA INFLE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html). Postgress has something equivalent. Most vendors should. Normally you would have to store the groomed CSV file (proper delimiters and quoting) on the DB server itself, so that is perhaps not even possible on remote DBs. But it is amazingly fast. It's almost worth putting a file upload micro service on the DB instance just to enable this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried with a statement ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017819/using-java-servlet-to-upload-a-csv-file-into-database?noredirect=1#comment106144056_60017819 ) but I couldn't get it to work. This is for my class project, we only have been on it for a couple months learning Java, and are obligated to use JPA/Hibernate. I started researching batch inserts for now.